# Jquery hotkeys can't send value with function

Tags: javascript, jquery, hotkeys, jquery-hotkeys

I'm wondering why this works with jquery hotkeys:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'm', dothis);
```

but this doesn't:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'm', dothis(6));
```

Even like this doesn't work:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'm', dothis());
```

Comment: the bind events accept a callback function not the result of a function

Comment: So what's the solution? you can only use functions with no values?

Comment: `dothis` provides the function *reference* which runs every time the event occurs. `dothis()` provides the *result* of the function at the point of defining the event handler only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must give the binding a *function as a parameter*.

In the second and third cases you are giving a *function call* which gets evaluated, and the returned value is given to the keybind function - presumably you do not return a function and that does nothing.

If you want to construct a new function with set parameters from a function you already have, use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

`$(document).bind('keydown', 'm', dothis.bind(null, 6));`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use curried function. Its function which returns function.

```
function doThis (num) {
  return function () {
    // Do something with num
  }
}

$(document).bind('keydown', 'm', dothis(6))
```